# Interaction term becomes more significant

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, interaction

Model(1):
Y = A + B + $W_1$ + A*B

Model(2):
Y = A + B + $W_{1,2,3,4,5}$ + A*B

A ranges from 0 to 70 while B ranges from 0 to 25; W refer to set of controls.

In model (1) A (p<0.01) and B (p<0.01) is significant but A*B is not significant (p=0.064).
Then after adding various controls that rids the bias off the variable of interest B...

In model (2) A (p<0.01) is still significant but B becomes not significant (p=0.106)
However, A*B is now significant (p=0.003).

Why is this so? I am quite baffled by these findings. How does one explain this phenomenon of an interaction term that is originally not significant becoming more significant thereafter when controls are added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the issue does not really have to do with the controls that you added but rather that one (or both) of your models suffers from [multicollinearity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity).

Multicollinearity means that it is possible to express one of the features as a linear combination of the other features. In turn, you can predict $Y$ using multiple different models that are all equally good.

If, for instance, you should out that $A^*B$, $A$ and $B$ were perfectly collinear then you could express $A^*B = A + B$. Thus, you can express Model (1) as

$Y = A + B + W_1 + (A + B) = 2A + 2B + W_1$

or

$Y = (A^*B) + W_1 = W_1 + 2A^*B$.

In a case like this, you'd be the same kind of weird significance results (basically $A$ and $B$ could be significant, or $A^*B$ could be significant; your program will report whatever the regression converges to).

There are different ways to [identify multicollinearity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity#Detection_of_multicollinearity)... though a straightforward approach is to run regressions between sets of features that you believe might be strongly associated, such as:

$A^*B = A + B + W_1$

$A^*B = A + B + W_{1,2,3,4,5}$

You'll be able to identify the issue if you get a really large $R^2$ value for one of them. If this turns out to be the case, then you can usually get more reliable results by standardizing your variables before running your regression.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am not quite sure about multicollinearity as an explanation. for e.g. if A and B were perfectly collinear; from what I know, one of them should be omitted, in which case I don't really get why A*B can be expressed as A+B since there would not be any beta coefficients that can be estimated from a perfectly collinear model. I have went ahead to try and identify multicollinearity as you have suggested, both equations with dependent A*B as you have stated results in R2 > 0.97. And finally, does standardizing mean normalising them? (i.e. if sample is >age24, make age24=0)

Comment: Just to add, wouldn't multicollinearity result in greater insignificance as opposed to being more significant? If we assume model(1) to be non-multicollinear, what can we then say about the controls that were added subsequently and its effect on the increase in significance of the interaction term?

Comment: @elks Ah that's what I thought! The R2 > 0.97 means that you can get 97\% of the signal from $A^*B$ using $A$ and $B$. Your model is definitely suffering from "strong" multicollinearity. It's just not perfect multicollinearity.

Comment: @elks I'm not sure what you mean by "if A+B were perfectly collinear, one of them would be omitted." Some regression software will automatically drop features that are identical to others... but this kind of omission would only happen for models where there was perfect collinearity (not the strong kind that you have here). The strong kind just makes the regression problem more difficult from a numerical perspective and results in weird behavior (for the reasons I mentioned above).

Comment: @elks Yeap standardizing the variables = normalizing = subtracting the mean and dividing by the st. dev.

Comment: @elks For your other question, multicollinearity would result in multiplicity of good models. In theory, this means that you could have multiple models that attain the same R^2 but where different subsets of the features are significant. Here, you can't really make significance statements about the set correlated features, which we know is contained in $A,B,AB,W$. Since the problem is numerically difficult, your software might report that $AB$ and $W$ is significant and $A$ and $B$ are not but these results may change using different software.